# Сохранение скриншота работы в Qt C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Помогите пожалуйста. У меня есть одна проблема, мне нужно сохранить результаты работы в программе в виде скриншота в папку, где находиться сама программа.

Вот main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    QScreen *screen = qApp->primaryScreen();
    int x = screen->virtualGeometry().width() / 2 - w.width() / 2;
    int y = screen->virtualGeometry().height() / 2 - w.height() / 2;
    w.setGeometry(x, y, 600, 300);
    w.show();
    QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
    return a.exec();
}
```

Вот эта строчка определяет путь, где должны создаваться папки, по пути выполнения программы:

```
QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
```

Вот как должны создаваться папки:

```
void MainWindow::hiding()
{
    QDir dir;
    dir.mkpath("./Results/");
    dir.mkdir("9 А");
    l_name1.mkpath("./Results/9 А/");
    l_name1.mkdir(ui->l9_1->text());
    saveSettings();
}

void MainWindow::on_start_2_clicked()
{
    QString dir("./Results/");
    QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(dir);
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);    
}
```

Ну и сам скриншот:

```
   grab().save("./Results/9 А/Л1 Складання та випробування електромагніту/" + name->value("names",  ui->textEdit->toPlainText()).toString() + "Завдання 2.png");
```

Но оно вместо того, чтобы создавать папку за папкой, делает вот что(три пустые папки):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оно делает то, что ей говорите )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `mkpath`, только в качестве аргумента укажите полный путь который необходимо создать:

```
QString path = "./Results/9 А/Л1 Складання та випробування електромагніту/";
QDir dir;
if( dir.mkpath(path) ) {
    // mkpath - вернет true даже если путь уже существует
    //Если все хорошо, то сохраняем файлы по этому пути
    grab().save(path + "<prefix>_Zavdannya_2.png");
} else {
    // Хьюстон, у нас проблемы...
}
```

Если же вам необходимо "задерживаться на этажах" ваших папок, то тогда после создания папки в нее необходимо войти:

```
QDir dir;
dir.mkdir(dirName);
dir.cd(dirName);
// делаем что-то очень важное в папке и создаем новую, вложенную
dir.mkdir(dirName2);
```

Теперь новые папки будут создаваться (при помощи объекта dir) внутри, то есть относительно директории `dirName` и так далее...

p.s. в качестве рекомендации, лучше в качестве имен папок и файлов использовать латиницу (можно и транслит) и пробелы заменять на знак подчеркивания `_`.

Comment: Если указывать полный путь, то все правильно работает. Но он у меня то динамический

Comment: @RomanKhvalko дополнил ответ